# Retrieve the lines from a cutplane in mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

How can I retrieve the lines from a cutplane in mayavi?

I've been able to retrieve the points, but I don't have the information about conectivity.

```
cutplane.cutter.outputs[0].points.to_array()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have found the points coordinates:

```
  PtsCoord = cutplane.cutter.outputs[0].points.to_array()
```

You can also find something called polys.to_array(). Maybe here :

```
  PolyAndTriIDs = cutplane.cutter.outputs[0].polys.to_array()
```

This variable contains indexes of points that form triangles and polygons, then you can extract all coordinates with these lines:

```
  jj=0
  while (jj < PolyAndTriIDs.shape[0]):
    if PolyAndTriIDs[jj] == 3:  # triangles

      x1,y1,z1 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+1],:]
      x2,y2,z2 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+2],:]
      x3,y3,z3 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+3],:]
      jj=jj+4

    else: # quadrilateral
      x1,y1,z1 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+1],:]
      x2,y2,z2 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+2],:]
      x3,y3,z3 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+3],:]
      x4,y4,z4 = PtsCoord[PolyAndTriIDs[jj+4],:]
      jj=jj+5
```

HTH